# What are the speaker tags when I enable Speaker diarization in Google Speech to text api?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

When I enable speaker diarization in google speech to text api, I get speaker tags for each word. What are those tags? What do they mean? When I give speaker count 2, I sometimes get tags 0 and 2 and sometimes 0 and 1 or sometimes I also get 0,1,2 though my speaker count is 2. So what those tags mean?

Comment: Every person who is talking in the video should have a unique speaker tag.

Comment: yes, but why am I getting 3 unique speaker tags when I am giving the speaker count as 2?

Comment: According to Google Speech to Text Documentation, using `speaker count` is deprecated. You should use the `SpeakerDiarizationConfig` and set `minSpeakerCount` and `maxSpeakerCount` range instead. Check: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#speakerdiarizationconfig

Answer (score 0):

You have set a speaker count of 2, and you are seeing speaker tags {0, 1, 2}.

Speaker 0 is the entire script and is not part of the diarized output. You can discard speaker 0 since it simply repeats the entire script and provides no unique information regarding the diarization.

With a speaker count of 2, speakers 1 and 2 will contain the entire script. I hope this helps.